# Lean object towards mouse threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to recreate a mouse interaction with an obj file - similar to this example:

http://yungjake.com/usb/

Additionally, I am trying to have it animate when clicked upon - and I really want to recreate the smoothness/physics of the mouse interaction when the mouse is hovering.

My code so far is hardly close but here it is:

```
<script src="three.min.js"></script>

    <script src="EffectComposer.js"></script>
    <script src="CopyShader.js"></script>
    <script src="DotScreenShader.js"></script>
    <script src="RGBShiftShader.js"></script>
    <script src="FilmShader.js"></script>
    <script src="FilmPass.js"></script>


    <script src="RenderPass.js"></script>
    <script src="MaskPass.js"></script>
    <script src="ShaderPass.js"></script>

    <script src="Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="OBJLoader.js"></script>


    <script>

        var camera, scene, renderer, composer;
        var object, light;
        var geometry;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);

            //

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.z = 20;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x000000, 1, 1000 );


            //=======================================================================================================================================================
            //=======================================================================================================================================================

                            // BACKGROUND

                            scene.background = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
                                    .load( [ 'px.jpg', 'nx.jpg', 'py.jpg', 'ny.jpg', 'pz.jpg', 'nz.jpg' ] );

                            var textureCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader()
                                    .load( [ 'px.jpg', 'nx.jpg', 'py.jpg', 'ny.jpg', 'pz.jpg', 'nz.jpg' ] );
                            textureCube.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;

                            var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
                            manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
                                console.log( item, loaded, total );
                            };


            scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );

            // postprocessing

            composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

            var effect = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.RGBShiftShader );
            effect.uniforms[ 'amount' ].value = .05;
            effect.renderToScreen = true;
            composer.addPass( effect );



            var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
            composer.addPass(renderPass);

            var effectFilm = new THREE.FilmPass( .5, 0, 0, false);
            effectFilm.renderToScreen = true;
            composer.addPass(effectFilm);


            var clock = new THREE.Clock();

            function render() {
                var delta = clock.getDelta();
                composer.render(delta); //parameter must be set with render
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
            }

            render();
            //

            //=======================================================================================================================================================
            //=======================================================================================================================================================


                            // MATERIALS + OBJ LOADER + TEXTURE

                            var texture = new THREE.Texture();

                            var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                                if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                                    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                                    console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                                }
                            };

                            var onError = function ( xhr ) {
                            };

            //=======================================================================================================================================================

                            var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: textureCube, refractionRatio: .25 } );

                            var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
                            loader.load( 'UV_Grid_Sm.jpg', function ( image ) {
                                texture.image = image;
                                texture.needsUpdate = true;
                            } );

                            var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
                            loader.load( 'WorkPlease.obj', function ( object ) {
                                object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                                    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                                        child.material.map = texture;
                                        child.material = material1;
                                    }
                                } );

                                window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
                                var mouse3D = new THREE.Vector3(
                                        ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
                                        - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
                                        2 );

                                object.lookAt(mouse3D);

                                var angle = Math.atan2(mouse3D.y-object.position.y, mouse3D.x-object.position.x);
                                object.rotation.z = angle;
                })
                                scene.add( object );



                                // object.position.y = 0;
                                // //
                                // object.position.x = 0;
                                // //
                                // object.position.z = 0;

                                //object.rotateOnAxis( 50, 50, 50 );

                                // object.center.x = 0;
                                // object.center.y = 0;
                                // object.center.x = 0;
                                //
                                // mesh.position.set( object.center.x, object.center.y, object.center.z );
                                // mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( -object.center.x, -object.center.y, -object.center.z ) );







                            }, onProgress, onError );








            function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) * .005;
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * .005;


            }


            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            //composer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            // object.rotation.x += 0.005;
            // object.rotation.y += 0.01;


        //  composer.render();

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Please let me know what I should change or if there are any tutorials that could help me out with this. I am a beginner so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can inspect the source code of the site you want to duplicate by using the developer tools in the console, or you can learn from the three.js examples, such as [this one](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap).

Comment: I have the source code but it is so elaborate it doesnt help me much.